# Is there a reasonably accurate heuristic for detecting the subject and object of an English sentence?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I realize that flawlessly separating subject noun phrases and object noun phrases from a sentence is an open research problem and is not easily explained here, but is there a smart way of doing this (assuming I already have a POS-tagged sentence) which works for most sentences, or at least relatively simple ones? I know that simply assuming the first noun phrase is the subject is a pretty good approximation, but in sentences beginning with prepositional phrases (e.g., "Across the clearing and through the stream ran the frightened deer."), this fails. Ideally, I'd like something which also recognizes the subject in this case.

For reference, that example sentence gives the following parse tree with the Stanford Parser:

`[ROOT [S [PP [IN Across] [NP [NP [DT the] [NN clearing] ] [CC and] [NP [IN through] ] ] ] [NP [DT the] [NN stream] ] [VP [VBD ran] [NP [DT the] [ADJP [JJ frightened] ] [NNS deer] ] ] [. .] ] ]`

My current strategy is as follows:

1. Subject: Do a BFS on the tree, looking for the first NP.
2. Verb: Do a BFS on the tree, looking for the first VP. On this subtree, do a BFS looking for a VB(D|G|N|P|Z).
3. Object: Do a BFS on the VP subtree found above, looking for a NP.

This strategy results in the following for my example:
`SUBJECT: (NP (DT the) (NN stream) ) , VERB: (VBD ran) , OBJECT: (NP (DT the) (ADJP (JJ frightened) ) (NNS deer) )`.

If possible, I'd like to modify my strategy to not fail on these cases, and eventually even more complicated cases.

Comment: you will need a parser like http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! have you tried [pattern's parse trees](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#tree)? they have a relations flag that might get you what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Ok, you are using the Stanford parser. Then the parser gives you the result. For example if I run it on `In London, my friend ate a big apple and a pear.` I get:

```
    (ROOT
      (S
        (PP (IN In)
          (NP (NNP London)))
        (, ,)
        (NP (PRP$ my) (NN friend))
        (VP (VBD ate)
          (NP
            (NP (DT a) (JJ big) (NN apple))
            (CC and)
            (NP (DT a) (NN pear))))
        (. .)))
```

Then subject is the NP under S (my friend) and object is the NP under the VP under S (a big apple and a pear). And actually the dependency parse:

```
prep_in(ate-6, London-2)
poss(friend-5, my-4)
nsubj(ate-6, friend-5)
root(ROOT-0, ate-6)
det(apple-9, a-7)
amod(apple-9, big-8)
dobj(ate-6, apple-9)
det(pear-12, a-11)
dobj(ate-6, pear-12)
conj_and(apple-9, pear-12)
```

tells you what is the head of the subject (friend) and of the direct object (apple,pear).

Obviously, the parser is not without errors, and actually on your sentence with inversion (subj follows the verb) it gets confused:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (PP (IN Across)
      (NP
        (NP (DT the) (NN clearing))
        (CC and)
        (NP (IN through))))
    (NP (DT the) (NN stream))
    (VP (VBD ran)
      (NP (DT the)
        (ADJP (JJ frightened))
        (NNS deer)))
    (. .)))
```

the correct parse would be

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (PP
        (PP (IN Across)
            (NP (DT the) (NN clearing)))
        (CC and)
        (PP (IN through)
            (NP (DT the) (NN stream))))
    (VP (VBD ran))
    (NP (DT the)
        (ADJP (JJ frightened))
        (NNS deer))
    (. .)))
```

Then you would correctly identify `the frightened deer` as the subject.

What to do about it? You can either try to improve the parser by retraining it on more sentences like this one (in addition to the ones they trained it on), but that is A LOT of work. Or you might try to identify the types of sentences it does not get right and focus on identify the errors. Not easy either. You can also try a different parser, like the one used in [LinGO project](http://lingo.stanford.edu/), but it is much harder to use (I think it requires lisp or something similar)

---

(This is the old answer, before I knew we have a result of a parser)

In addition to the POS tagger, I  would get a [chunker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757947/what-is-a-chunker-in-natural-language-processing) and then:

- subject is the first (top level) NP (noun phrase). In your *Across the clearing* sentences, the NP would be part of a prepositional phrase (PP), so you would not pick it up; it would still fail as there is inversion.
- object is the (top level) NP immediately following the finite verb, if any.

Depending on the chunker, you might miss coordinated NPs, possibly strip NPs of their PPs (getting `my friend` instead of `my friend from New York`).

If you cannot afford to run a chunker, just look for the head of the subject/object:
 - N or subject pronoun (*we* but not *us*), preceding the finite verb (but keep in mind there are sentences like `John and me went to the store`.
 - N or object pronoun (*us* but not *we*), if any. You should add a check that NP, which the N is part of is immediately following the verb and it is not a part of a PP). Say you can check the verb is immediately followed by `(Det) ((Adv) Adj)* N)`

You should also consider questions (where the subject follows the finite verb and object follows the base verb: `Do YOU see THE APPLE?`). You could also deal with inversion by requiring a subject and looking for it after the verb if you do not find it before, but that would cause problems with imperative (`Eat the deer!`). Not sure it is worth it.

Obviously, slightly unusual sentences such as sentences with unbounded dependencies will throw you off (`Kim, Sandy knows Chris trusts` where `Kim` is the object of `trusts`). If you need reasonable answers in such cases you need to run a real parser.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Maybe I should have elaborated; I'm using Stanford CoreNLP, which gives me the entire parse tree, so I probably don't need to use a "chunker". I'm not super concerned with questions, and even less so with imperatives, I just want to be sure I am extracting the subject and object of "normal" sentences as accurately as possible. As you already mentioned, simply taking the NP after the verb to be the subject fails sometimes, but I'm not sure if there is much I can do about this.

Comment: If it gives yout the parse tree, then subject is simply the NP under S (next to VP) and object is the first NP under VP (if any). That's it.

Comment: Again, this only works for simple sentences, and I was hoping there might be a heuristic that would work for a wider range of cases (as in the example I gave where the subject is last), but it's entirely possible there isn't.

Comment: Unless the parser makes an error, you can still get the subject from it by taking the NP directly under the S (regardless of its position). Can you post the bracketed tree you get for that sentence?

Comment: The parser (englishPCFG.ser.gz) does make an error on your sentence. It thinks that stream is the subject. If you add a comma after the preposed adjunct (which I believe is the proper way to write it in US English) it does not help much - the parser just thinks the sentence has not subject.

Comment: The tree is [ROOT [S [PP [IN Across] [NP [NP [DT the] [NN clearing] ] [CC and] [NP [IN through] ] ] ] [NP [DT the] [NN stream] ] [VP [VBD ran] [NP [DT the] [ADJP [JJ frightened] ] [NNS deer] ] ] [. .] ] ].

The parser doesn't seem to be "making an error" per se, it still correctly identifies the VPs, NPs and PPs. There just seems to be no general rule for deciding which NP is the subject in this case.

Comment: Also, I've edited the question to explain my current isolation strategy.

Comment: No it does make an error, the `[NP [DT the] [NN stream] ]` should be next to `[IN through]` within `[PP [IN through] [NP [DT the] [NN stream] ]`. That way you would not consider stream as a candidate for subject or object at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to verify this fact now, but in a meeting a couple of weeks ago someone stated that there are only a few thousand verbs in the English language.

It would seem that if you could identify the verb (by brute force?) then the subject and object would be on either side of it.

Comment: i dont think that's possible in today's English, where you have verbalized nouns, e.g. "he googled for something".

Comment: This may be true (at least to a reasonable degree of accuracy), but it wouldn't handle cases where the subject appears at the end of the sentence (as in the example I gave).

Comment: He said the sentences are POS-tagged, so no need to identify verbs as they are already identified (moreover you need to know if the verb is finite or not)

Comment: Ahhhh ... POS is "part of speech." I *knew* it wasn't what came to mind first, but for the life of me I couldn't think of what!